# Converting space delimited text file using python?

Tags: python, json, text, type-conversion, whitespace

I am trying to convert this space delimited text file into columns and rows (I want to eventually convert it to JSON). My script can't separate the cols probably,  mainly because I am looking for whitespaces. I can't change the formate of the input (text file coming in)

I am having issues with the format of the file, this is a very simple example

```
col1 col2                 col3 text                      col4

1403 bash                 2014-07-28 22:32:53 UTC+0000   sudo bash
1464 bash                 2014-07-28 22:32:28 UTC+0000   sudo root
```

*when I parse the file I get this for the data below the dashes:*

```
['1403', 'bash', '2014-07-28', '22:32:53', 'UTC+0000', 'sudo', 'bash']
```

*I want it to look like this:*

```
['1403', 'bash', '2014-07-28 22:32:53 UTC+0000', 'sudo bash']
```

This is a very basic example. but basically I am mapping out the headers to the data below the dashes. let me know if you can help with anything.

NOTE: The output does not have to be exactly as shown, I just want to be able to separate the cols data.

Here is what I have in code so far this separates out the headers to individual cols:

```
colNames = testFile.readline()
#tempList = re.split('(\s )', colNames)
headerList = []
for i in tempList:
    j = i.replace(' ','')
    if j != '':
        headerList.append(j)
```

Then I have a loop to go through the data based on the position of the data(this is where I believe I need to find a way to better separate the data):

```
   for line in testFile.readlines():
        if rowCounter > 0:
            row = line.split()
            print row
            for i in range(len(headerList)):
                colNameDic.update({headerList[i]:row[i]})
            rowDic = dict(colNameDic)
            fileList.append(rowDic)
            rowDic = {}
        rowCounter +=1
```

Comment: You parse the file incorrectly. You need a fixed-column parser, such as `pandas.read_fwf()`.

Comment: You need to post your code. And, as was said in the previous comment, it's not a single space delimited file. It's 1, then 15(?), then 3 spaces

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I tried focusing on the space difference but some files have alot of space while other don't.  for example if you notice there is only once space between col1 data and col2 data, but both are different cols. Makes sense?

Comment: @DYZ Ill check that out. just posted code (sorry its my first time)

Comment: are you sure that it is `col3 text` and not, e.g., `col3_text` with an underscore, or a point, or a comma... because with the space the structure of the header it's different from the structure of data rows

Comment: @gboffi yea man. its sucks how its formatted. its all literally space delimited and there is not consistency at least non I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the header row had no *extraneous spaces* in the names of the columns one could split the data lines using the `slice` builtin function (please note that I have added an underscore into the header row to normalize the names of the columns)

```
In [20]: h = 'col1 col2                 col3_text                      col4\n'
In [21]: r = '1403 bash                 2014-07-28 22:32:53 UTC+0000   sudo bash\n'
In [22]: fields = h.split()
    ...: ifields = [h.index(f) for f in fields]+[None]
In [23]: slices = [slice(i,j) for i, j in zip(ifields, ifields[1:])]
In [24]: tokens = [r[s] for s in slices]
In [25]: tokens
Out[25]: 
['1403 ',
 'bash                 ',
 '2014-07-28 22:32:53 UTC+0000   ',
 'sudo bash\n']
In [26]:
```

PS  you may want to `rstrip` the individual items, `[r[s].rstrip() for s in slices]`.

---

***Addendum***

If it is possible to find a discriminant between valid column names and garbage, the no extraneous spaces requirement can be relaxed... re your specific data format (no underscores...)

```
In [35]: h = 'col1 col2                 col3 text                      col4\n'
In [36]: r = '1403 bash                 2014-07-28 22:32:53 UTC+0000   sudo bash\n'
In [37]: fields = [f for f in h.split() if f[:3]=='col']
In [38]: ifields = [h.index(f) for f in fields]+[None]
In [39]: slices = [slice(i,j) for i, j in zip(ifields, ifields[1:])]
In [40]: tokens = [r[s].rstrip() for s in slices]
In [41]: tokens
Out[41]: ['1403', 'bash', '2014-07-28 22:32:53 UTC+0000', 'sudo bash']
In [42]:
```

Comment: yeah I have the headers figured out, its mainly the rows that bug me. I am gonna test this out.

Comment: here I have used a simple, perfect match, you could use a regexp, a validating function, whatever you see fit

Comment: quick question tokens extracts all the rows correct?

Comment: If the fields/tokens have the same length in each row, yes. OTOH if the data writer had chosen to overflow rather than truncate, your boat is in bad waters...

Comment: What I mean in the prev comment, look at field#1, it looks like a PID, doesn't it? what happens if the PID is 5 digits? it is still OK, but if it's 6 digits (not possible for a PID if my recollection is exact, just an example) you possibly are in trouble...

Comment: Actually  can I  edited the post. the headers are not the same words. each header is a different name. but there are __________ under each column. look at the new post?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot fully make sense of your last comment... Re _"not the same words"_, maybe you could edit your question and _show the actual header lines_ in place of what you have shown until now, couldn't you?  also the stuff about underscores, please what do you _exactly_ mean? Eventually you speak of a new post, but looking 
 at [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3429617/user3429617) I  cannot see a new post...

Answer (score 0):

As long as the column widths are fixed, you can use a fixed-width parser:

```
pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(data), skiprows=[1], 
            parse_dates=["col3 text"], # Optional
            colspecs=[(0,4),(5,25),(26,54),(57,66)])
#   col1  col2            col3 text       col4
#0  1403  bash  2014-07-28 22:32:53  sudo bash
#1  1464  bash  2014-07-28 22:32:28  sudo root
```

Comment: yeah the widths are not fixed. Thank you tho. this still helps!

Comment: If you do not have fixed columns and do not have one delimiter, then your only hope is to write a regular expression that describes a row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach: Do a two-pass processing over the rows of text. In the first pass, we will guess the start indices: The indices where a non-space character was preceded by a space. For each row, the start indices might be slightly different, but if we look at those indices where they are **all** in common, then those indices might be the starts of the columns. The guessing of the start indices are not perfect. It requires that none of the cell in a row are missing

In the second pass, we will use those indices to split a row into columns, trim off the trailing white spaces.

```
import itertools

def split_columns(row, start_indices):
    start_indices = start_indices + [None]
    a, b = iter(start_indices), iter(start_indices)
    next(b)

    columns = []
    for istart, istop in zip(a, b):
        columns.append(row[slice(istart, istop)].strip())

    return columns

def guess_start_indices(row):
    row = ' ' + row
    prev_seq, cur_seq = iter(row), iter(row)
    next(cur_seq)

    start_indices = []
    for i, (prev, cur) in enumerate(zip(prev_seq, cur_seq)):
        if prev == ' ' and cur != ' ':
            start_indices.append(i)
    return set(start_indices)

def find_common_start_indices(rows):
    start_indices = set.intersection(*(guess_start_indices(row) for row in rows))
    start_indices = sorted(start_indices)
    return start_indices

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('columnize.txt') as rows:
        first_pass, second_pass = itertools.tee(rows)

        start_indices = find_common_start_indices(first_pass)
        print(start_indices)

        for row in second_pass:
            print(split_columns(row, start_indices))
```

Notes

- In the code, I created two iterators `first_pass` and `second_pass` to help iterating over the rows of text. These iterators are important because they allow to iterate over the rows twice without rewinding the file.
- The theme of this approach is guessing, so there will be text which fools the coding and it will make wrong guesses
- Therefore, use this solution as a starting point and do verify the output